# targeting ranges of divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following on my book site: http://seanbooks.tumblr.com

1. The first three div's with the class "book" should have the class
   "fourcol," and the rest should have the class "threecol."
2. Every 4th instance of "threecol" should have the class "last"

I am wondering if there is a way to target the first 3 instances of the "book" class using I tried using http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
<script>
    $(".book").slice(0, 3).addClass('fourcol').removeClass('threecol')
    .filter(':nth-child(3)').addClass('last').end()
    .filter(':nth-child(4n)').addClass('last');
</script>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) slectors

```
$('.book').filter(':lt(3)').addClass('threecol').end() //sets class to first three
          .filter(':gt(2)').addClass('fourcol').end() //sets class to the rest
          .filter(':nth-child(4n)').addClass('last'); //every fourth
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz2Yw/1/)

Comment: That is really good use of `end()` never knew of that function actually but if I am reading the code right I think this won't work since it will do the nth filter on `.book` but some of the books now come under `fourcol` and the OP only wants `threecol` books to have the last class.

Comment: @Sammaye - Not really sure what the OP wants, as long you're using `nth-child` or `index()` it does'nt really matter if you select the `.threecol` class or not, as they all have an index over four, and the index will be what order they are in relative to the parent anyway. If the point was to get every fourth element only in that particular class, you would have to something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cz2Yw/3/) anyway ?

Comment: Though correction cos I realised your code is different between the two, but yes that latest fiddle works :)

Comment: I updated my post, based on what worked after I played with the FIDDLE you made :)

Comment: @SeanThompson That was kinda bad to change the marked answer then, SO doesn't notify me when stuff like that happens, would have been good to have notified me that you unaccepted my answer, anyway glad you got a better answer :)

Comment: ah, I'm sorry! I am such a newb :(

Comment: @SeanThompson ah it's ok just something for next time :) though I have just posted something on meta about it not notifying me and just saying -15 randomly, might get a positive response, hopefully

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using slice here as it says on the man page for lt():

> Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

So for example:

```
$(".book").slice(0, 3).addClass('fourcol').removeClass('threecol');
```

Here is an example of selecting every 4th instance using JQuery nth selector:

```
$(".threecol .book:nth-child(4n)").addClass('last');
```

Comment: Thank you Sammaye, and everyone else for helping me understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".book:lt(3)").addClass('fourcol').removeClass('threecol');
```

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

To select every 4th instance of the class "threecol" you can filter out those elements that are not 4th instance.

```
$(".threecol").filter(function(i){
    return (i+1)%4 = 0;
}).addClass('last');
```

Comment: that works great! Any idea how you would target every 4th instance of the class "threecol" and assign it a class of "last"?

Comment: @SeanThompson You can use the nth selctor: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".book").addClass('threecol') //add a class of threecol to each element
          .slice(0, 3).addClass('fourcol').removeClass('threecol'); //add fourcol only to the first three elements
```

I don't know if I understood this part correctly, but for the "4th intance" you could do:

```
var count = 0
$(".threecol").each(function() {
    count++;
    if(count === 4) {
        this.className += " last";
        count = 0;
    }
});
```

or you could try using [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) like:

```
$(".threecol:nth-child(4n)").addClass("last")
```

Comment: Ah it's actually every 4th instance, not just 1.

Comment: with nth child you could try :nth-child(4n)

Comment: @SeanThompson there you go, I've updated the answer with the jQuery code, good luck :)